# What is the output of the program with reason?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
void f(int *p,int *q){
    p=q;
    *p=2;
}
int main(){
    int i=0,j=1;
    f(&i,&j);
    printf("%d%d\n",i,j);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is 02
can somebody explain this?

Comment: Are you sure? it should be `02`, and there is a typo with the quotes in `printf`

Comment: Does this compile? And what do *you* think its output should be?

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: I pick this program from an previous year examination paper and there were 4  options 1)22  ,2)21 ,3)01 ,4)02 According to there Answer sheet answer is 22

Comment: I rarely downvote a question but since the code does not compile (wrong use of quote marks in “%d%d\n” instead of "%d%d\n") and also because it does not output `22`, I will.

Comment: But according me Answer Should be 21

Comment: @MohitShukla what was the output of your program? Was it 1)22, 2)21, 3)01, or 4)02 ?

Comment: @WeatherVane according to that paper answer is 22

Comment: There's no "pass by reference" in this code. C doesn't have pass by reference, C++ does.

Comment: @MohitShukla stuff your paper - what did your test program produce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See annotations:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int *p, int *q) // p contains address of i, q contains address of j
{
  p=q;                 // p now contains address of j
  *p=2;                // assigns 2 to j, not i
}

int main()
{
  int i=0,j=1;               // i contains 0, j contains 1
  f( &i, &j );               // call f with pointers to i and j
  printf( "%d%d\n", i, j );  // after call to f, i is unchanged, j contains 2
  return 0;
}
```

Output will be 02, not 21 or 22.  The answer sheet you're referring to is incorrect.

**Edit**

It's a sad fact of life that many of the people teaching C programming don't know the language that well.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the output should be 02.

```
void f(int *p,int *q){
    p=q;
    *p=2;
}
```

The above function takes two `int` pointers (or addresses), and makes them both point to the same thing (`p=q` means p points to whatever q does, or p is the same address as q) and then changes the value being pointed to to 2 (using the dereference operator, `*p`). Since the `main()` function in your question calls `f()` using addresses of `int`s, it changes the value of the `int` at the second parameter address (in this case, `j`'s address).

So after calling this function on the addresses of `i` and `j` as in your main function, `i=0` still, and now `j=2`

Then when you format the string and print both values without a space in between, you get the string "02".

Comment: Wrong conclusion. The value of `i` is not changed in `f` since `p=q;`. The output should be `02`.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the program in a terminal, you'll see `02` on the screen and the cursor will be placed on the next line in the first column. Here's why:

1. You set two variables `i=0` and `j=1`.
2. The memory addresses of each variable name are passed into the function.
3. The function then receives the variables as pointers and to retrieve the actual values, they must be dereferenced (prefixed by a star).
4. `p=q` means set the memory address of p to the same memory address q has which in turn causes the first parameter of the function unchanged and that makes the value of i unchanged.
5. `*p=2` means set the value at address P to 2 which also changes the value of j to 2.

If you choose to remove the line `P=Q`, then the result would be `21` instead of `02` because you're modifying contents at address P which is variable i.

Then printf shows the values of varibles i and j followed by a new line. and finally, the program returns a value of 0 to whatever application called it.